# Finding identical consecutive entries in a list and finding how many consecutive entries there are

Tags: python

I have a list of Boolean values such as

```
bool_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

and  I need to make a list of lists in a way as such [[a,b],[c,d],...] where the first entry in the lists (e.g. a and c) are the index number of the first True in bool_list where there are 2 or more consecutive True entries (a=0 and c=4 in this case)  and second entry in the lists (e.g. b and d) are the number of consecutive True entries in bool_list (b=2 and d=4 in this case). How do I write a code to solve that without importing anything new. Thanks :).

Comment: "How do I write a code to solve that without importing anything new" so numpy is not an option.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, or suggest some options? This sounds like a homework question, and the best way you'll learn is to try. I suggest trying using a `for i in range(len(bool_list)):` loop and doing some forwards and backwards indexing using `bool_list[i]` and `bool_list[i+1]` to check for consecutive items. You'll probably also need to append things to an empty list by creating it using `empty_list = []` then appending things using `empty_list.append(i)`. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use importing?

Answer (score 0):

A generator based implementation with only built-ins:

```
def gen(bl):
    count = true_start = 0
    for i, b in enumerate(bl):
        if b:
            if not count:
                true_start = i
            count += 1
        elif count > 1:
            yield (true_start, count)
            count = 0
    if count:
        yield (true_start, count)

>>> bool_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
>>> list(gen(bool_list))
[(0, 2), (4, 5)]
```